# Python bx.intervals and Intersection

Tags: python, intersection, intervals

Question about how the start and end positions of an Intervals in bx-python are encoded.

```
from bx.intervals.intersection import Intersecter, Interval
tree = Intersecter()
tree.add_interval( Interval(1, 10))
tree.add_interval( Interval(11, 20))
tree.find( 1,1 )
[]
tree.find( 2,2 )
[Interval(1, 10)]
tree.find( 9, 9 )
[Interval(1, 10)]
tree.find( 10, 10 )
[]
```

It looks like the boundaries are not included in the Intervals. I did not find any documentation about that. Is there a way to include the boundaries in the interval ?